# Tabs in Accordion to left and content to right

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Im using jquery Accordion, i want to align the hearders in the left like a list so that when the user clicks on the header the content should populate in the right.
I couldnt achieve this using the jquery ui accordion. it shows the content below the hearder which i dont need..

Take a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/qkXUJ/

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3><a>tab 1</a></h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... </div>
    <h3><a>tab 2 </a></h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... </div>
</div>
h3{
    float: left;
}
```

initially i get the hearder in left but upon clicking the second header it moves up. I want to stay it below the first hearder.

Help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is likley not an answer to your specific question, and may be better as a comment, but I think you want the jQuery Tabs widget, with a vertical implementation rather than the Accordian.

Try this link and see if that helps:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical